# Reduce the repetition in less project

Tags: less

I have a couple of less files that are very repetitious. I would like to follow the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle as much as possible.

Here is a snippet:

```
.margin-loose {
    margin-top: @loose;
    margin-bottom: @loose;
}
.margin-loose-top {
    margin-top: @loose;
}
.margin-loose-bottom {
    margin-bottom: @loose;
}
.margin-loose-sm {
    margin-top: @loose-sm;
    margin-bottom: @loose-sm;
}
.margin-loose-top-sm {
    margin-top: @loose-sm;
}
.margin-loose-bottom-sm {
    margin-bottom: @loose-sm;
}
.margin-loose-xs {
    margin-top: @loose-xs;
    margin-bottom: @loose-xs;
}
.margin-loose-top-xs {
    margin-top: @loose-xs;
}
.margin-loose-bottom-xs {
    margin-bottom: @loose-xs;
}
```

Is it possible to use Less mixins or loops to shorten this file?

Comment: My personal preference would include a change to the way you set up your classes. For instance: `margin-loose` would set margins, `margin-xs` would set smaller margins, `margin-top-only` would set said margin amounts only on the top, etc. This would involve HTML redesign to use both classes instead of the one. The current formula would get easier if LESS actually includes a way to concatenate on class names (I'm not 100% familiar with its features).

Comment: Vague questions asking to DRY up code are not considered on-topic (see: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295665/are-dry-questions-on-topic).  You seem to think that mixins or loops would do the job, but did you *try* writing any?

Comment: Sorry, I should have read the guidelines.